# Python pillow package: AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I use pillow package but it seems that **textsize** method is deprecated, so how can I get the **width** and the **height** of the text?

```
def generate_images(lines):
    os.makedirs(current_output_images_path, exist_ok=True)
    font_size = 20
    font = ImageFont.truetype(kurdish_font, font_size)
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        text_img = Image.new('RGB', (3, 3))
        text_width, text_height = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img).textsize(line, font=font)

        image = Image.new("RGB", (text_width + 20, text_height + 20), "white")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

        x = 10
        y = 10

        draw.text((x, y), line, fill="black", font=font, direction="rtl")

        image_name = f"line_{index + 1}.png"
        image_path = os.path.join(current_output_images_path, image_name)
        image.save(image_path)
```

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#font-size-and-offset-methods